# Consulta en Laravel con relaciones Muchos a Muchos

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

[image: Relaciones producto-categorias y producto-proveedor]

Necesito una consulta bien sea Eloquent o simple SQL que me pueda dar los **productos** que tengan la categoria **tecnología** y a su vez pertenezcan al proveedor con el id **7**

Las relaciones en ambos casos son de Muchos a Muchos donde exite una tabla pivot para cada relacion M-M con el id de cada tabla padre

Espero me puedan ayuda.

Comment: Puedes agregar el SQL de la creación de las tablas? y con los insert correspondientes, esto ayudaría para crear la consulta y después probarla

Answer (score 1):

Despues de muchos intentos lo logre con ELOQUENT

```
$products = Product
        ::whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('name', 'technology');
        })
        ->whereHas('providers', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('id', 7);
        })
       ->get();
```

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido, +1.